# fazer um componente em um repeater ficar enabled=false

Tags: c#, asp.net

Tenho um botão dentro de um repeater. Como está em um repeater, ele só aparece no DataBind() do repeater. Usando a variável e do evento, consigo chegar a esse componente assim:

```
protected void rptDocumentosRepeater_ItemDataBound(object source, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
        {
            //Declarações
            try
            {
                //Instancias e Inicializações
                //Desenvolvimento
                if (....)
                {
                    e.Item.FindControl("fiuDocumentoUpload").
                }
            }
            catch
            { throw; }
        }
```

Acontece que eu preciso dar um Enabled=false e não consigo. Nesse comando  `e.Item.FindControl("fiuDocumentoUpload").` eu não consigo trazer o Enabled. Consigo o Visible, mas o Enabled não. Como eu faço?

Declaração dele no Asp.Net

```
<td class="ajusteTdIe">
    <asp:FileUpload ID="fiuDocumentoUpload" runat="server" CssClass="acessos" />
</td>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Já tentou fazer o casting pro seu tipo de componente?

```
var componente = (FileUpload)e.Item.FindControl("fiuDocumentoUpload");

if(componente != null)
    componente.Enabled = false;
```

Comment: Fiz conforme o seu exemplo, mas dá erro de: Object not set for a instance of object

Comment: Os Ids do FileUpload não mudam no repeater?

Comment: Você se refere a quais ID's? Se for os ID's dos itens sim, mas apenas esses. Quanto a esse: fiuDocumentoUpload, aí não.

Answer (score 0):

Como o outro amigo disse, você precisa fazer um cast. 
Tentei adicionar como comentário na resposta mas ainda não tenho pontuação suficiente para isso (sou novo aqui). 
Creio que sua exception no cast ocorreu no momento em que ele passou por outro elemento da lista e tentou fazer um cast. Use o cast com "as" que ele trará null caso o cast não seja possível, assim:

```
var componente = e.Item.FindControl("fiuDocumentoUpload") as FileUpload;
if(componente != null)
    componente.Enabled = false;
```

Ou, verifique o tipo de objeto antes, assim:

```
var componente = e.Item.FindControl("fiuDocumentoUpload");
if (componente is FileUpload)
    ((FileUpload)componente).Enabled = false;
```